# What's the best way to handle XML in Python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, openstreetmap, elementtree

I am working on an XML file that is very large (I think that since about it is 45 GB) I have to search through the document of OpenStreetMap data and find a particular path that satisfies a certain criteria. I am currently using [XML element tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) however I think it is a little slow since I need to search the XML for specific Geographic coordinates. Is there a better way to do this ? 
I have also seen a little bit of [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) however, I'd like to know if there's a better choice between the two ? Thank you!

Comment: If you have to do this over and over again then you should think about importing the data into a spatial database.

Answer (score 0):

The [sax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html) package is well suited for parsing huge `xml` files that can't be loaded into memory all at once. The parser will go "line-by-line" and notify you when it encountered the beginning or ending of an element, instead of loading the file into memory, parsing it, and giving you the whole tree.